# Is there anyway to find out the ssid of the wifi access point within the browser using javascript?

Tags: javascript, wifi, ssid

Is there anyway to find out the ssid of the wifi access point you are connected to within the browser using javascript?

If there isn't my guess would you'd have to write a plugin for it.  I bet ActiveX allows this.

Comment: If this can't be done, then how is it that Firefox 3.5 determines your location based on the location of surrounding wireless access point ssid's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't and for a good reason :)

*Update:* I should have elaborated, JavaScript is run inside a browser sandbox that was designed to protect both security and privacy. ESSID of AP you're connected to is of course not a secret, but it's also not an information that should be revealed without ones consent.

Comment: @Adam No really, what's the reason?  It's public information anyway.

Comment: @Adam Oh definitely, I agree with that.  But what if you had the option to give it permission?  

I was thinking that since AP's are actual geographic positions on a map, that as a hack they could have their ssid set to thier lat lon coordinates to let your browser know approximately where you are (if you gave it permission of course)

Comment: If approximate location is enough for your needs you could consider using GeoIP services.

Answer (score 3):

Using Javascript?  No.

I would be extremely surprised to find that there's a non-OS/Browser-specific hack to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done.

JavaScript is quite well shielded from the hardware and environment it is running on.  All JavaScript 'knows' is that it has an internet connection it can use.  It doesn't know whether it's broadband, 3G, ethernet, wireless or any of the details - just that it's there.

How worrying would it be for a user if they were innocently browsing the internet and websites could collect intimate details about their hardware as they went!?  This would be open to huge amounts of abuse as someone, somewhere would surely work out a way of turning it to their advantage!